# Checking if an element belongs to an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to check if an element belongs to an array using ruby. I'm reading from a file (say demo.txt) which has comma separated pairs in each line. I'm concatenating these two pairs and pushing it into an array. Later I need to check if a specific value belongs to the array. I can see the array is populated successfully but the second check is unsuccessful, i.e. it can't find the element in the array. 'My demo.txt' is as follows

```
a, b
c, d
```

The ruby code goes as follows

```
array = Array.new
File.readlines('demo.txt').each do |line|   
    line.slice! ", "
    array.push line
end
array.each do|d|
    puts d
end

if array.include? 'ab'
    puts "correct" #this is not printed
end
```

How do I check if the array contains the element 'ab'?

Comment: debug it. see what array contains

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When printing the array it shows the elements as  'ab' and 'cd'.

Comment: As for you question, `array.include? 'ab'` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `ab\n` in your array.

Instead of

```
array.each do|d|
    puts d
end
```

use inspect to check the values,

```
p array
#=> ["ab\n", "cd"]
```

---

To fix the issue, use `chomp` on `line`

```
File.readlines('b.txt').each do |line|   
    line = line.chomp
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see the issue.

Comment: Even better would be to put the chomp right after the readlines: `File.readlines('b.txt').map(&:chomp).each ...`.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing this

```
if array.include? 'ab'
    puts "correct"
end
```

with this one

```
if array.find 'ab'
    puts "correct"
end
```

resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you. This sure works. But I prefer the answer given by @Wand Maker, since it strips the newlines before pushing it to array.